# Mysql DDL works on local wamp but does not import on online server

Tags: mysql

I am using this schema on localhost wamp MySQL server and it works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblcustomers` (
`customerid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`customername` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`customerphone` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`customeraddress` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`registrationdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
UNIQUE KEY `credid` (`customerid`),
UNIQUE KEY `credname` (`customername`),
UNIQUE KEY `customerid` (`customerid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=110 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1067 - Invalid default value for 'registrationdate'
```

When I import the dump file on online server I get the message above. How to deal with it?

Comment: Are you running different MySQL versions on the two machines? What versions?

Comment: yes. schema was built upon MySQL version 5.6.17 and now trying to import on 5.5.36 version

Comment: In MySQL 5.6 you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for both `TIMESTAMP` and `DATETIME` column, but in 5.5 and older it can only be used for `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: But changing data type to TIMESTAMP does not help either

Comment: @Barmar: please check it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05320

Comment: It works here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/43857e

Comment: @Barmar ... Thanks a million man for your great help

Answer (score 1):

change datatype for `registrationdate` FROM `DATETIME` to `TIMESTAMP` and you should be through

Comment: Sorry, it does not help either

Comment: This seems like it should work. The documentation clearly says that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is allowed for `TIMESTAMP`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html